# Django Serialiser get sibling records

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django DRF, I am trying to work out I can return objects siblings. For instance, I have record B, can i return records A and B also?

I can then use these to cycle blog posts for example with previous and next article links.

At the moment, i am getting the current object, and then calling the database again looking for record with same parent. I am thinking there might be more efficient way.

This is how i am doing it currently, with an action. I give the service_id of current object, that in turn finds the service siblings via parent_id, and the lower id. If one exists, it returns it. If not, then i get null. So essentially it would remove the need to call this action:

```
@action(
        detail=False,
        methods=["get"],
        url_path=r"get-prev-service/(?P<service_id>[\w]{0,50})",
    )
    def get_prev_service(self, request, service_id=None):
        current_service = self.queryset.get(pk=service_id)
        queryset = (
            self.queryset.filter(
                parent=current_service.parent, id__lt=current_service.id
            )
            .exclude(pk=current_service.id)
            .order_by("-id")
            .first()
        )
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=False)

        if queryset:
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response()
```

Or can achieve same like so:

```
@action(
        detail=False,
        methods=["get"],
        url_path=r"get-related-services/(?P<service_id>[\w]{0,50})",
    )
    def get_related_service(self, request, service_id=None):
        current_service = self.queryset.get(pk=service_id)

        queryset = (
            self.queryset.filter(
                parent=current_service.parent, id__gt=current_service.id
            )
            .exclude(pk=current_service.id)
            .order_by("-id")
            .first()
        )
        queryset2 = (
            self.queryset.filter(
                parent=current_service.parent, id__lt=current_service.id
            )
            .exclude(pk=current_service.id)
            .order_by("-id")
            .first()
        )

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=False)
        serializer2 = self.get_serializer(queryset2, many=False)

        return Response({"prev": serializer.data, "next": serializer2.data})
```

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code that represents what are you doing now? Not quite clear what those siblings are

Comment: Added, hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is actually OK because all querysets in Django are lazy objects and evaluated only on access. This means that your "complex" query will select only one item from the database per execution.

If you need an improvement, you may select only a single field `parent_id` from queryset. I.e.:

```
    parent_id = self.queryset.filter(
        pk=service_id).values_list('parent_id', flat=True).first()
    
    # this will produce SQL query:
    # SELECT your_app_service.parent_id from your_app_service 
    # WHERE your_app_service.id = service_id   

    queryset = (
        self.queryset.filter(
            parent_id=parent_id, id__lt=service_id
        )
        .exclude(pk=service_id)
        .order_by("-id")
        .first()
    )

    # and this one will give you the following query:
    # SELECT <all_fields from model> FROM <table> 
    # WHERE (parent_id = parent_id AND id < service_id 
    # AND NOT(id = service_id)) ORDER BY id DESC
```

And then `.first()` will just pick the first item from this cursor (without fetching all the elements from DB).

Answer (score 0):

Just another answer came in mind suddenly.

If you use ModelViewSet from DRF - you will have this functionality built-in with paginator.

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

So then each request to a single object will have additional tags for `previous` and `next` objects if you also set `limit` and `offset` as URL params. For example:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://10.100.102.10:8004/garage/customers/?limit=1&offset=1'
```

Will return:

```
{
    "count": 13,
    "next": "http://10.100.102.10:8004/garage/customers/?limit=1&offset=2",
    "previous": "http://10.100.102.10:8004/garage/customers/?limit=1",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "passport_number": 8,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "email": null,
            "age": 7,
            "city": null
        }
    ]
}
```

So you can use then links from response to go back and forward through items